# Leafpad edit over SFTP connection

Tags: raspbian, remote, lxde

Leafpad is the default text editor for *.php* files on my pi. I believe this is the default setting... and it works fine for local files.

I connected my pi to an SSH server via SFTP so I can browse the files through a PCManFM window, but when I try to open files from the remote server, Leafpad opens a blank *(Undefined)* window.

I'm looking for other LXDE text editors to see if a different one will accommodate... but I've used gedit in Ubuntu like this with no problems, so I'm not sure why this is not working as expected?

I realize this is probably more of a general Linux question, but I'm wondering if someone has had a similar issue and found a workaround/fix?

Comment: Well, I found _gedit_ is available, so I installed it and it seems to work for what I want, but can I do this without the gnome dependency???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `sshfs` rather than `sftp` for this.

You may need to:

```
# apt-get install sshfs
```

Then create a directory in your home directory:

```
$ mkdir remote
```

Then connect it up:

```
$ sshfs user@remote_system:/path/to/remote/directory /path/to/local/directory
```

Then you can use the remote filesystem as if it is local and open your files in Leafpad.